# No managed connections available within configured blocking timeout (30000 [ms])

Tags: hibernate, jboss, wildfly, jta, wildfly-10

I use WildFly V 10.1.0 with Mysql Database.

I have defined max pool size as 100 in the datasource configuration in standalone.xml

But Still I'm getting following exception[1];

I do not see any network issue. What other settings I need to add?

**My persistence.xml**

```
<persistence-unit name="adb-persistence-unit"
    transaction-type="JTA">
    <description>Forge Persistence Unit</description>
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/testDS</jta-data-source>        
    <shared-cache-mode>ALL</shared-cache-mode>
 <property name="jboss.as.jpa.providerModule" value="org.hibernate:5.2"/>

        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size" value="5" />   
   <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size" value="500" />  
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout" value="1800" />     
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements" value="100" /> 
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period" value="3000" /> 
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment" value="5" />  
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.validate" value="false" />
```

I open session like;

```
    @PersistenceContext
        protected EntityManager entityManager;
        private Criteria criteria;
        private Session session;

   session = getEntityManager().unwrap(Session.class);
```

[1]

```
/20/2016 9:52:04 AMCaused by: java.sql.SQLException: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000453: Unable to get managed connection for java:jboss/datasources/testDS
10/20/2016 9:52:04 AM   at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrapperDataSource.getConnection(WrapperDataSource.java:146)
10/20/2016 9:52:04 AM   at org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources.WildFlyDataSource.getConnection(WildFlyDataSource.java:66)
10/20/2016 9:52:04 AM   at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122)
10/20/2016 9:52:04 AM   at org.hibernate.internal.NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.java:35)
10/20/2016 9:52:04 AM   at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.acquireConnectionIfNeeded(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:99)
10/20/2016 9:52:04 AM   ... 225 more
10/20/2016 9:52:04 AMCaused by: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000453: Unable to get managed connection for java:jboss/datasources/testDS
10/20/2016 9:52:04 AM   at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.getManagedConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:656)
10/20/2016 9:52:04 AM   at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.tx.TxConnectionManagerImpl.getManagedConnection(TxConnectionManagerImpl.java:429)
10/20/2016 9:52:04 AM   at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.allocateConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:747)
10/20/2016 9:52:04 AM   at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrapperDataSource.getConnection(WrapperDataSource.java:138)
10/20/2016 9:52:04 AM   ... 229 more
10/20/2016 9:52:04 AMCaused by: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000655: No managed connections available within configured blocking timeout (30000 [ms])
10/20/2016 9:52:04 AM   at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedDequeManagedConnectionPool.getConnection(SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedDequeManagedConnectionPool.java:565)
10/20/2016 9:52:04 AM   at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.AbstractPool.getTransactionNewConnection(AbstractPool.java:699)
10/20/2016 9:52:04 AM   at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.AbstractPool.getConnection(AbstractPool.java:598)
10/20/2016 9:52:04 AM   at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.getManagedConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:590)
10/20/2016 9:52:04 AM   ... 232 more
10/20/
```

**Edit**

**Datasource**

```
     <datasources>
            <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/testDS" pool-name="lobDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true" use-ccm="true">
                <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://${env.MYSQL_PORT_3306_TCP_ADDR:db.xx.com}:${env.MYSQL_PORT_3306_TCP_PORT:3306}/${env.MYSQL_DATABASE:testdb}?failOverReadOnly=false&amp;maxReconnects=10&amp;zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull&amp;autoReconnect=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8&amp;characterSetResults=UTF-8&amp;useUnicode=true&amp;interactiveClient=true&amp;sessionVariables=storage_engine=InnoDB</connection-url>
                <driver>mysql</driver>
                <pool>
                    <flush-strategy>IdleConnections</flush-strategy>
 <max-pool-size>100</max-pool-size>  
                </pool>
                <security>
                    <user-name>${env.MYSQL_USER:admin}</user-name>
                    <password>${env.MYSQL_PASSWORD:ss_password}</password>
                </security>
                <validation>
                    <check-valid-connection-sql>SELECT 1</check-valid-connection-sql>
                    <background-validation>true</background-validation>
                    <background-validation-millis>60000</background-validation-millis>
                </validation>
            </datasource>
```

Comment: how does your datasource configuration look like? as hibernate.c3p0.* properties are ignored and it is using datasource defined in datasource subsystem of the server.

Comment: Why do you need session? (you should be able to handle persistence  with EntityManager only)

Comment: @ctomc I have provided my datasource confiugration and persistence.xml configuration. How can I modify my configuration then?

Comment: @JohnDonn I use Criteria  API (not hql) to query database. criteria = getSession().createCriteria(getEntityClass());

Comment: @Ratha you may use EntityManager to work with JPA criteria https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/04/jpa-2-0-criteria-query-with-hibernate.html . Also, as far as I know, in Wildfly the standard way to do persistence is with JPA and EntityManager, so I think it is better to avoid working with Hibernate directly, unless it is really necessary.

Comment: @JohnDonn Thanks, I'll Try to use JPA dand entitymanager. Currenlty this is bit urgent to sort out connection issue. Is there any other way I can provide settings in my datasource?